# How to use/import PyCrypto in Django?

Tags: python, django

I am trying to use PyCrypto with Django. I import it like this:

```
from Crypto.Cipher import AES
```

But it says:

```
ImportError: No module named 'Crypto'
```

But when I try it using the Command Prompt, it is working.

Other details (if it can help):

I am using Eclipse Luna with PyDev installed. My OS is Windows7 32 bit.

Comment: Are you sure you're using the *same python* for django and prompt ?

Comment: Wait, I will check. Thanks for the pointer.

Answer (score 2):

By using pip you can install pycrypto in virtualenv of your django project.

```
pip install pycrypto
```

And then import `from Crypto.Cipher import AES`in your required views.py file. It will support for `Django==1.9` and `python <=3.4`